# ui and server script running as one script working fine. However running script in different file ui.R and server.R throws error

Tags: r, shiny

I want to run ui.R script and server.R script in separate files and run together to publish in shiny server.
But throwing error :
**"Error in serverFuncSource() : 
  server.R returned an object of unexpected type: list"**

refer to the link:
[I want to render website through login page in shinyApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670587/i-want-to-render-website-through-login-page-in-shinyapp/57672052?noredirect=1#comment101794758_57672052)

I referred the above link to run script and publish in shinyserver.
I am not able to publish it while running ui and server in single script.
So, I want to split the ui script and server script in separate files and publish it in shiny server.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating as below.

global.R file:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyauthr)
library(shinyjs)

# dataframe that holds usernames, passwords and other user data
user_base <- data.frame(
    user = c("user1", "sr1"),
    password = c("pass1", "USR@1"), 
    permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
    name = c("User One", "User Two"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    row.names = NULL
)

jscode <- "
shinyjs.hrefAuto = function(url) { window.location.href = url;};
"
```

ui.R file:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    # must turn shinyjs on
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = "hrefAuto"),
    # add logout button UI 
    div(class = "pull-right", shinyauthr::logoutUI(id = "logout")),
    # add login panel UI function
    shinyauthr::loginUI(id = "login"),
    # setup table output to show user info after login
    #tableOutput("user_table")
    uiOutput("hptm")
)
```

server.R file:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # call the logout module with reactive trigger to hide/show
    logout_init <- callModule(shinyauthr::logout, 
                              id = "logout", 
                              active = reactive(credentials()$user_auth))

    # call login module supplying data frame, user and password cols
    # and reactive trigger
    credentials <- callModule(shinyauthr::login, 
                              id = "login", 
                              data = user_base,
                              user_col = user,
                              pwd_col = password,
                              log_out = reactive(logout_init()))

    # pulls out the user information returned from login module
    user_data <- reactive({credentials()$info})

    #output$user_table <- renderTable({
    # use req to only render results when credentials()$user_auth is TRUE
    output$hptm <- renderUI({req(credentials()$user_auth)
        js$hrefAuto('https://stackoverflow.com')})
}
```